# Update env file in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure build pipeline and I want to update the .env file when deploying to the dev environment. Below is the deployment stage,

```
- stage: 'deploy_to_DEV'
jobs: 
- job: deploy_to_dev
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  enabled: true
  inputs:
    source: 'current' 
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

- script: |
    echo "REACT_APP_DEV_API_KEY=Test" > '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/.env'

- script: |
    cat '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/.env'

- script: pwd && ls -alR '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  enabled: true
  displayName: "Deploy Dev01"
  name: DeployDev01
  inputs:
      workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/'
      app_location: './'
      output_location: './'
      skip_app_build: true
      skip_api_build: true
      verbose: true
      is_static_export: true
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(dev-token)
```

By default the content of the .env file are,

```
REACT_APP_DEV_API_KEY=Original
```

After I run the following scripts,

```
echo "REACT_APP_DEV_API_KEY=Test" > '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/.env'
cat '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/.env'
```

The following content is printed on the console,

```
REACT_APP_DEV_API_KEY=Test
```

This means that the content of the file has been updated. But after the pipeline is finished successfully, my REACT app is still showing the value

> Original

Why the file is not updated on the Azure Static Web when I update it before copying and the updated file should be copied to the target?